# Different Methods in PHP Classes depending on server?

Tags: php, class

I wrote a little PHP Blogscript with classes but ended in a problem. i have 2 webspaces and on 1 it works, on the other it doesn't.

i have defined a class called $system and within this class there is a function called `the_querystring`. it just returns an array with all the exploded `querystring` entries.

```
<?php $system->the_querystring()['variable']; ?>
```

my problem is - on 1 server it works fine, on my other server  i have to write

```
<?php $system->the_querystring(['variable']); ?>
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-89) the notation

```
$secondElement = getArray()[1];
```

is allowed from PHP 5.4

Maybe your webserver has a PHP version older, something like

```
$querystring = $system->the_querystring();
$querystring['variable'];
```

should work on both.